# Fastest way to populate wx.Choice?

Tags: python, wxpython

Need to populate a `wx.Choice` with hundreds of choices, and it looks like there's only one method for this, which is `Append()`:

```
choiceBox = wx.Choice(choices=[], id = wx.ID_ANY, parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 289),
                                          size=wx.Size(190, 21), style=0)

for item in aList:
    choiceBox.Append(item)
```

I've tried to append a whole list all at once but it won't work, so is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what ??? you just give it to choices

```
choiceBox = wx.Choice(choices=aList, id = wx.ID_ANY, parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 289),
                                      size=wx.Size(190, 21), style=0)
```

you can also do it later with

```
choicebox.SetItems(aList)
```

here is a simple example where generating the choices takes a long time , but we use threading to not block the ui

```
import wx
import threading 
import time
import random
def make_choices():
    choices = []
    for _ in range(80):
        choices.append(str(random.randint(0,1000000)))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Making choice List!"
    return choices

def make_choice_thread(wxChoice,choice_fn):
    wx.CallAfter(wxChoice.SetItems,choice_fn())
    wx.CallAfter(wxChoice.SetSelection,0)

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
fr = wx.Frame(None,-1,"A Big Choice...")
st = wx.StaticText(fr,-1,"For Some reason you must pick from a large list")
ch = wx.Choice(fr,-1,choices=["Loading...please wait!"],size=(200,-1),pos=(15,15))
ch.SetSelection(0)
t = threading.Thread(target=make_choice_thread,args=(ch,make_choices))
t.start()
fr.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: oops fixed the `SetItems`

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't know there's `SetItems` for the job, but sadly, it doesn't seem to be any faster at all, both `Append` and `SetItems` took about 2 seconds to populate `choiceBox` with 1800 items, so I guess there's no better choices to speed this up?

Comment: That just sounds like a bad idea. What user would want to scroll through 1800 items outside of a grid or listctrl? Not many. You could try using a ComboBox or ComboCtrl, but you might want to rethink your UI a bit.

Comment: Put the listctrl populating code in a thread. At least that won't block your GUI

Comment: @user2963623 thats true but he needs to know how to do GUI threading (ie only the main thread can update the gui)